# Change selected text when selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do you change the selected text in a select box using jQuery?

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Name">
        <option>John</option>
        <option>Mike</option>
    </optgroup> 
</select>
```

ie, when you select John. The select box would show, "Name: John". Instead, of just "John".

Comment: you could do something like <option value="John"> Name:John </option> to achieve that.

Comment: @tiagobolt - But the OP only wants the menu option to change once the option is selected.

Comment: but, then that would display an option that says "Name: John" wouldn't it? I just want that to display when they select John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html:

```
<select id="myselect">
    <optgroup label="Name">
        <option>John</option>
        <option>Mike</option>
    </optgroup> 
</select>
```

js:

```
$("#myselect").change(function (event) {
    var o = $("#myselect option:selected")
    , v=o.text()
    , old = $("#myselect option:contains('name')")
    , oldv = old.html();

    oldv && old.html(oldv.replace('name: ',''));
    o.text('name: ' + v);
});
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/eQR2W/2/

Comment: sorry, missed the '#' off. try now :)

Comment: ahh, should've looked into it closer. This is a lot closer to what I want. Except that when you click the drop down, you would see the "name: John" as an option. Switching this to answer now.

Comment: Hi again. This is really confusing me a bit. Could you maybe explain the answer some more? How it works and stuff. particularly this line: `oldv && old.html...`

Comment: oldv && old.html... is there to prevent an error. the first time the event fires, no option starts with "name: " so there is nothing to replace. the code to the right of && only executes if oldv has a value.

Comment: @herotwist- tried to update it to make it work for two or more categories. I seem stuck. [help?](http://jsfiddle.net/eQR2W/4/) or should I just ask another question?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#name-select').change(function() {
        var selectedItem = $('#name-select option:selected');
        var oldValue = selectedItem.text();
        var newValue = 'Name: ' + oldValue;
        selectedItem.text(newValue);
    });
});
```

You would need to update your select option to give it an ID though:

```
<select id="name-select">
    <optgroup label="Name">
        <option>John</option>
        <option>Mike</option>
    </optgroup> 
</select>
```

And here's the jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/benmajor/2m76z/

Comment: Of course you'll likely want to update that to remove 'Name: ' once the option is no longer selected for any practical application.

Comment: Yes, I can work with this. just have to figure out how to change it back like @Oren said.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a value attribute to the option you could use something like this (and you need to add a value attribute otherwise you will loose the value if someone selects a value and then selects another value).

```
$("select").change(function () {
   var label = $("select option:selected").parent().attr("label");
   var val = $("select option:selected").attr("value");
   $("select option:selected").html(label+":"+val);
});
```

Comment: hmm..maybe do something like, var oldList = $("select").html()? hmm.. thanks for the ideas.