# How can I make this code work better?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, algorithm, logic

I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578221/change-selected-text-when-selected) about manipulating the html select box with jQuery and have gotten this really short and sweet code as an answer.

```
$("#myselect").change(function (event) {
    var o = $("#myselect option:selected"),
    v=o.text(),
    old = $("#myselect option:contains('name')"),
    oldv = old.html();

    oldv && old.html( oldv.replace('name: ', '') );
    o.text('name: ' + v);
});
```

I have one problem. This code doesn't work on multiple categories and I can't seem to wrap my mind around how it can be done. So, I made the obvious changes to it:

```
$("select").change(function (event) {
    var foo = $("select option:selected"),
        bar = foo.text(),
        cat = foo.parent().attr("label"),
        old = $("select option:contains('" + cat + "')"),
        oldbar = old.html();

    oldbar && old.html( oldbar.replace(cat + ': ', '') );
    foo.text(cat + ': ' + bar);
});
```

This now works on multiple optgroups/categories but has led to another bug. A more problematic one, at that.

It happens when you click from one category to another. Check it out on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GNaT/3/light/).

Comment: Having the comma **after** the line break makes my eyes itch.

Comment: What is the bug? I seem to get the expected behavior in both Chrome and FF. (edit : nm I see it, the name of the category gets added to the dropdown)

Comment: @Shaz, yeah happened to me too. I got used to it. @goggin13, the bug happens when you click on one category option (say, Saab) then going to the other (Harley) and going back to Saab.

Comment: @Shaz +1 I couldn't take it either so I did everyone a favor and cleaned it up.

Comment: @nolabel - I absolutely hate that style too, but it is a valid style and I think it's bad form to go around forcing your preferred style on OPs

Comment: What is the 'algorithm' tag doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the last snippet is it uses the name of the current category to locate the last selected label to flip back.  Instead, how about searching for the ":",  (this won't work if you have ":" in one of your options), and then replacing that part of the string.

change line 5 to:

```
, old = $("select option:contains(':')")
```

and line 8 to:

```
oldbar && old.html(oldbar.replace(oldbar.substr(0, oldbar.indexOf(':') + 2),''));
```

Let me know if that's not working for you!

Edit: as an afterthought, you might consider adding this line

```
$('select').change();
```

As well, somewhere in the $(document).ready() event, so that when the page first renders the default value gets the prefix like (I think) you want.

Comment: This answer was so profound I had facepalm twice. I was so busy finding a way to remember the last category that I couldn't see the easier/better solution. Thank you, for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

I've renamed the variables since it is really a good habit to get into naming your variables and functions with meaningful names so you can juggle in your memory what is going on.

```
$("select").change(function () {
    // We immediately invoke this function we are in which itself returns a function;
    // This lets us keep lastCat private (hidden) from the rest of our script,
    // while still giving us access to it below (where we need it to remember the
    // last category).
    var lastCat;
    return function (event) {
        var selected = $("select option:selected"), 
            selectedText = selected.text(),
            cat = selected.parent().attr("label");
        if (lastCat) { // This won't exist the first time we run this
            oldSelection = $("select option:contains('" + lastCat + ":')");
            oldHTML = oldSelection.html();
            oldHTML && oldSelection.html(oldHTML.replace(lastCat + ': ', ''));
        }
        selected.text(cat + ': ' + selectedText);
        lastCat = cat; // Remember it for next time
    };
}()); // Be sure to invoke our outer function (the "closure") immediately, 
// so it will produce an event function to give to the change handler, 
// which still has access to the variable lastCat inside
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shot in the dark. At first blush, it appears you're not saving the previous selection and you're using the selection which triggered the event in your *oldbar && old.html( oldbar.replace(cat + ': ', '') );* line. You need to save the category of the previous selection in a separate var.